# MergExt using mergBLE for bluetooth communication between iOS and Arduino

Tags: bluetooth

Would "mergBLE" be an appropriate purchase for use with interaction with an iOS device (e.g. iPad, etc) and Arduino UNO or MEGA using Bluetooth?  Specifically, I need iOS / Arduino connectivity via Bluetooth, using LiveCode as a development platform, for data exchange....not internet, not WiFi... only localized Bluetooth data sends and receives.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely! I've recently been using mergBLE on iOS and it works great for what I'm doing. (If this doesn't do it, then I don't think you have any other option on LiveCode, so you might as well try.)